# Move a div that was created using Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, html

What I really want is to be able to click on the newly created div then click somewhere else on the screen and have the div move there.

My code:

```
$(function() { 
   $('a#linkA').click(function() {
      $('#container')
      .prepend("<div id='cloneA' onclick='moveA();'> <img src='A.gif' alt='A' </div>")
   });
});

function moveA(event) {
    var posx = event.pageX;  //get the mouse's x coord 
    var posy = event.pageY; //get the mouse's y coord   
    document.getElementById("cloneA").style.left = posx;
    document.getElementById("cloneA").style.top = posy;
```

When I run this in firefox and use firebug, it says "document.getElementByID("cloneA").style.left isn't defined...Why is that and what can I do to get this to do what I want? 
Thanks!

Comment: try add position: absolute; for 'cloneA', also append 'px'

Comment: Any reason you don't use `$('#cloneA').click()` to add the `moveA()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of different issues. One, you're not passing an event to `moveA(event)`. Also, when you set the `left` and `top`, you need to add a type of dimension to the value you set `left` and `top` to (`px`, `%`). And, to set the `left` and `top`, you need a `position: absolute` or a `position: relative` to make the `#moveA` move to that position.

Additionally, if you're going to add multiple `#moveA img`'s, you should really append a unique number to those element's `ID` attribute.

```
$(function() {
   var $container = $('#container');
   $container.data('count', 0);
   $('a#linkA').click(function() {
      var img = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=64&';
      var id = "cloneA"+$container.data('count');
      $container.prepend("<div id='"+id+"'><img src='"+img+"' alt='A'/></div>");
      $container.data('count',$container.data('count')+1);
      $('#'+id).click(function(event){
          moveA(event);
      });
   });
});

function moveA(event) {
    var posx = event.pageX;  //get the mouse's x coord
    var posy = event.pageY; //get the mouse's y coord
    var div = event.currentTarget.id;
    document.getElementById(div).style.position = 'relative';
    document.getElementById(div).style.left = posx+'px';
    document.getElementById(div).style.top = posy+'px';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WkkCE/

Comment: See my last edit I just added. Also, please upvote and mark as the answer if you feel it answers the question. `:)`

Comment: Your edit is also very helpful :D 
I would upvote, but apparently you have to have "15 reputation".

Comment: That's right; I always forget that. No worries, I appreciate you trying. `:)`